# Please how can I fix this error in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' in 'C:\Users\ANNOH\Desktop\React_Portfolio\react-portfolio\node_modules@fortawesome\react-fontawesome'
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome/index.es.js 1:0-64
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' in 'C:\Users\ANNOH\Desktop\React_Portfolio\react-portfolio\node_modules@fortawesome\react-fontawesome'

webpack compiled with 1 error

```
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.scss'
import LogoS from '../../assets/images/logo-s.png'
import LogoSubtitle from '../../assets/images/logo_sub.png'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faHome } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const Sidebar = () => (
    <div className='nav-bar'>
     <Link className='logo' to='/'>
        <img src={LogoS} alt="logo" />
        <img className='sub-logo' src={LogoSubtitle} alt="slobodan" />
     </Link>
    <nav>
        <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" to="/" >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} color="#4d4d4e" />
        </NavLink>
    </nav>
  </div>
 )
 
export default Sidebar
```

Comment: Similar to your questions asked here. also you can see the solution there https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/issues/236#issuecomment-865061578

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you followed the necessary steps in order?

https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
```

```
npm i -- save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't install node modules from package.json.
If you use npm you have to do `npm install`.
Or if you use yarn you have to do `yarn install`.
If you already installed node_modules from package.json, then if you still have the issue, I suggest to delete node_modules directory and redo `npm install` or `yarn install`

Comment: The first comment fixed the error. But I also ran the command.